# Create a List of Dates in Access Query

Tags: ms-access

I have a MakeTable query in Access that I am working on. I want to make it so that one of the fields in the table being created will be a list of dates in chronological order from 1/2/2015 to 11/30/2015. How is this done in Access query design view?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create a query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Abs([id] Mod 10) AS N
FROM 
    MsysObjects;
```

Save this as `qdxNumber10`

Now create a query with a *Cartesian Join* (multiplying) to generate your dates:

```sql
SELECT 
    DateAdd("d",[qdxNumber10_0].[N]+[qdxNumber10_1].[N]*10+[qdxNumber10_2].[N]*100,#2/1/2015#) AS [Date]
FROM 
    qdxNumber10 AS qdxNumber10_0, 
    qdxNumber10 AS qdxNumber10_1, 
    qdxNumber10 AS qdxNumber10_2
WHERE 
    DateAdd("d",[qdxNumber10_0].[N]+[qdxNumber10_1].[N]*10+[qdxNumber10_2].[N]*100,#2/1/2015#) <= #11/30/2015#;
```

Use this as source when you create your table.

To generate all dates for the current year, use:

```sql
SELECT 
    DateAdd("d",[qdxNumber10_0].[N]+[qdxNumber10_1].[N]*10+[qdxNumber10_2].[N]*100,DateSerial(Year(Date()),1,1)) AS [Date]
FROM 
    qdxNumber10 AS qdxNumber10_0, 
    qdxNumber10 AS qdxNumber10_1, 
    qdxNumber10 AS qdxNumber10_2
WHERE 
    DateAdd("d",[qdxNumber10_0].[N]+[qdxNumber10_1].[N]*10+[qdxNumber10_2].[N]*100,DateSerial(Year(Date()),1,1)) <= DateSerial(Year(Date()),12,31);
```

or use `DateSerial` directly:

```sql
SELECT 
    DateSerial(Year(Date()),1,1+[qdxNumber10_0].[N]+[qdxNumber10_1].[N]*10+[qdxNumber10_2].[N]*100) AS [Date]
FROM 
    qdxNumber10 AS qdxNumber10_0, 
    qdxNumber10 AS qdxNumber10_1, 
    qdxNumber10 AS qdxNumber10_2
WHERE 
    DateSerial(Year(Date()),1,1+[qdxNumber10_0].[N]+[qdxNumber10_1].[N]*10+[qdxNumber10_2].[N]*100) <= DateSerial(Year(Date()),12,31);
```

Comment: I wish I could spend more upvotes on this post because I would.  Mind = blown.

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a table with three fields:

```
[Snapshot Date]   date
[CountA]          number
[CountB]          number
```

Fill the `Snapshot Date` column in with a wide range of dates (yours inclusive) -- you can do this through code or just cut/paste from a spreadsheet.

Then save a crosstab query similar to this:

```
TRANSFORM Avg([All Dates].[CountB]) AS DeleteMe
SELECT [All Dates].[CountA]
FROM [All Dates]
WHERE [All Dates].[Snapshot Date] Between #1/2/2015# and #11/30/2015#
GROUP BY [All Dates].[CountA]
PIVOT [All Dates].[Snapshot Date];
```

(once you save this query, you should be able to switch to design view and see what the designer looks like)

Assuming the crosstab query above was named `All Dates Crosstab`, you could:

```
select *
into [My New Table]
from [All Dates Crosstab]
```