# Time gap calculation in MS Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, subquery

I have a table (Access 2016) tbl_b with date/time registrations
b_customer (num)
b_date (date)
b_start (date/time)
b_end (date/time)

I want to make a chart of all time registrations per day in a selected month and the gaps between those times. For this I need a query or table showing all times as source for the chart. I’m a bit lost how to approach this.
I assume the chart source needs consecutive records with all date and time registrations to do this. My approach would be create a temporary table (tmp) calculating all time periods where the customer is null. The next step would be a union query to combine the tbl_b and tmp table.
The tbl_b does not have records for every day, so I use a query generating all days in the selected month which shall be used in the chart (found this solution here: [[Create a List of Dates in Access Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34142019/create-a-list-of-dates-in-access-query][1]))

The disadvantage of using a tmp table for the “time gaps” is that it is not updating real time, where a query would provide this opportunity. I have about 20 queries to perform the end result, but MS Access keeps giving (expected) errors that the queries are too difficult.
Every query looks for difference between the in the previous query found end time and the next start time. On the other hand this approach has a weaknes as well, I thought 15 steps would be enough (no more than 15 gaps expected), but this is not sure.

Can anyone give me a head start how this can be accomplished by an easier (and actual working) method? Maybe VBA?

Thx!

Art

Comment: Hard to visualize without actual Sample data and Sample expected output.
Does the GAP belong to the prior row or to the next row?  Can that be computed once for all existing rows, and added to the Insert sql for new rows?

Comment: I'd dump it into excel, and use a formula (and its charting routines, as well) Just cos you have a hammer doesn't make everything a nail