# FIll in missing date gaps in Access table with prior day data using vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am importing data into a table that includes data for the month, but only on weekdays.  I need add weekend and holiday dates to the table with the data for the prior date date (i.e. Friday's data should repeat for Saturday and Sunday)  Additionally, I need this to occur for 2 groups of data within the table.

Example of my Data

```
As of Date  Group  Amount1  Amount2  Amount3
10/1/2019   Test1   $50.00   $60.00   $70.00
10/1/2019   Test2   $50.00   $20.00   $80.00
10/2/2019   Test1   $54.00   $62.00   $73.00
10/2/2019   Test2   $51.00   $25.00   $81.00
10/3/2019   Test1   $52.00   $61.00   $70.00
10/3/2019   Test2   $54.00   $23.00   $82.00
10/4/2019   Test1   $50.00   $60.00   $70.00
10/4/2019   Test2   $55.00   $25.00   $85.00
10/7/2019   Test1   $52.00   $62.00   $72.00
10/7/2019   Test2   $53.00   $24.00   $82.00
```

I need the data to look like the following:

```
As of Date  Group  Amount1  Amount2  Amount3
10/1/2019   Test1   $50.00   $60.00   $70.00
10/1/2019   Test2   $50.00   $20.00   $80.00
10/2/2019   Test1   $54.00   $62.00   $73.00
10/2/2019   Test2   $51.00   $25.00   $81.00
10/3/2019   Test1   $52.00   $61.00   $70.00
10/3/2019   Test2   $54.00   $23.00   $82.00
10/4/2019   Test1   $50.00   $60.00   $70.00
10/4/2019   Test2   $55.00   $25.00   $85.00
**10/5/2019   Test1   $50.00   $60.00   $70.00
10/5/2019   Test2   $55.00   $25.00   $85.00
10/6/2019   Test1   $50.00   $60.00   $70.00
10/6/2019   Test2   $55.00   $25.00   $85.00**
10/7/2019   Test1   $52.00   $62.00   $72.00
10/7/2019   Test2   $53.00   $24.00   $82.00
```

Rows for the missing weekend dates (10/5/2019 and 10/6/2019) need be inserted into the table and filled with data from 10/4/2019 for both groups.  This needs to loop for every missing date (weekend date or holiday) for the month.

Comment: Use VBA. Open a recordset of all Friday records for whatever period you need to do this for, loop through recordset and run 2 SQL INSERT actions to create records for Saturday and Sunday.

Comment: Would you be able to share VBA code to do this.  I am a novice :)

Comment: SO is not intended to be a code writing service. However, this was simple coding so I have provided an answer. If you don't have any basic programming skills, I suggest you study some tutorials.

Comment: You can create a series of consecutive days with https://stackoverflow.com/a/34152145/9439330. Now select amounts of the max day smaller or even the day of the list. SQL only no VBA, but of course needs some query experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to accomplish. This is very simple code and will not prevent duplicate entries. Could set table with a compound index on AsOfDate and Group fields to prevent duplicate pairs. Group is a reserved word and really should not use reserved words as names for anything. Also advise not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters in naming convention.

Use your table and field names where appropriate. Add date range criteria to WHERE clause if you want to reduce size of dataset.

```
Sub MakeRecs()
Dim db As DAO.Database, rs As DAO.Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Weekday([AsOfDate])=6")
Do While Not rs.EOF
    db.Execute "INSERT INTO Table1(AsOfDate, [Group], Amount1, Amount2, Amount3)" & _
            "Values(#" & rs!AsOfDate + 1 & "#,'" & rs!Group & "'," & rs!Amount1 & "," & rs!Amount2 & "," & rs!Amount3 & ")"
    db.Execute "INSERT INTO Table1(AsOfDate, [Group], Amount1, Amount2, Amount3)" & _
            "Values(#" & rs!AsOfDate + 2 & "#,'" & rs!Group & "'," & rs!Amount1 & "," & rs!Amount2 & "," & rs!Amount3 & ")"
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: [CurrentDb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.currentdb) in any loop is slow, as it creates a copy of database instance each time (where once is sufficent!) it is callled. If you want to avoid`With`or var declaration just use`rs.Parent`

Comment: Modified to use database object variable. I have never seen rs.Parent and could not figure it out.

Comment: `.Parent`is a hidden property (object browser -> show hiden elements) and holds reference to db, otherwise calls to rs members would fail like they do if you create a `TableDef`with `Set tdf = CurrentDb.TablesDefs("myTable")`and then e.g. call `tdf.Fields`. Errors because database instance created by`CurrentDb` ( a copy of the actual database, usualy`DbEngine(0)(0)`) was destroyed as reference counter gets zero  Cause rs.Parent holds a ref ( counter > 0) that doesn't happen for recordsets.

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Not a single issue with it.  Thank you so much!!