# Sql query to split the rows according to date range one day using sql query in Ms access

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, days

Example

Existing Table

```
Id name col3  ... Startdate EndDate   days

1 ABC value... 01-jan-2020 03-Jan-2020 3

2 AB value... 01-feb-2020 10-feb-2020 5

3 AC value... 02-feb-2020 02-feb-2020 1
```

Required result

```
Id name col3 ... Startdate EndDate  days

1 ABC value ...01-jan-2020 01-jan-2020 1

1 ABC value ...02-jan-2020 02-jan-2020 1

1 ABC value ...03-jan-2020 03-jan-2020 1

2 AB value... 01-feb-2020 01-feb-2020 1

2 AB value... 02-feb-2020 02-feb-2020 1

2 AB value... 03-feb-2020 03-feb-2020 1

2 AB value... 04-feb-2020 04-feb-2020 1

2 AB value... 05-feb-2020 05-feb-2020 1

3 AC value... 02-feb-2020 02-feb-2020 1
```

I need a sql query to keep all columns unchanged, and update the dates in a interval of one day,
Split the dates and place one in days column.
If we have only one then no change if there are more days then we have to split the dates and put one in days column as shown above.

Comment: Why do you show 5 days for second record?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a List of Dates in Access Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34142019/create-a-list-of-dates-in-access-query)

Comment: Accomplishing this by query alone in Access can perform very slowly with large dataset. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/61d24850-4e74-4272-919e-94f448a38ebc/access-add-records-for-days-within-date-range Probably faster to use VBA and write records to a table. https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=932864

Answer (score 1):

@June7 is right. VBA is the right tool for this:

```vb
Public Function ExpandTable()

    Dim Records     As DAO.Recordset
    
    Dim ThisId      As Long
    Dim ThisName    As String
    Dim ThisCol3    As String
    Dim EndDate     As Date
    Dim NextDate    As Date
    
    Set Records = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * From TableTest Order By Id, StartDate")
    
    Records.MoveFirst
    While Not Records.EOF
        If ThisId <> Records!Id.Value Then
            ThisId = Records!Id.Value
            NextDate = Records!StartDate.Value
            EndDate = Records!EndDate.Value
            If NextDate < EndDate Then
                Records.Edit
                    Records!EndDate.Value = NextDate
                Records.Update
            End If
        End If
        While NextDate < EndDate
            ThisName = Records!Name.Value
            ThisCol3 = Records!Col3.Value
            NextDate = DateAdd("d", 1, NextDate)
            Records.AddNew
                Records!Id.Value = ThisId
                Records!Name.Value = ThisName
                Records!Col3.Value = ThisCol3
                Records!StartDate.Value = NextDate
                Records!EndDate.Value = NextDate
            Records.Update
        Wend
        Records.MoveNext
    Wend
    Records.Close
    
End Function
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This could be sped up by using `WHERE Days<>1` or `WHERE StartDate<>EndDate` when opening the recordset, as you don't need to process some records.

Comment: Can you please add the how to connect to access and database and then run this query please

Comment: How to do this is a particular table in a database

Comment: The posted code is _VBA_ and will run in Access. Just replace the table name `TableTest` with that of your actual table.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in MS Access if you have a `tally` table of some sort.  This is a table that simply contains numbers.  You can create one by inserting rows into a table that only has an identity column.

With such a table, you could use:

```
select id, name, . . . 
       dateadd("d", n.n - 1, startdate) as startdate,
       dateadd("d", n.n - 1, enddate) as enddate,
       1 as days
from t inner join
     tally as n
     on n.n <= t.days;
```

Note:  MS Access makes it really hard to create a tally table within a query.  This is somewhere between easy and trivial in other databases.