# MS Access / VBA - How can I split rows in a Date Range

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have the following table and i want to split the date range into multiple rows if the start date and the end date have a difference greater than 1 month and depending on how many months were in that period split the "net price" in that many pieces.

The Existing table looks like this:

| MesspNr | RechnNr | AbDat | BisDat | NettBetr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ALT_102420 | 1 | 01.04.2016 | 30.06.2016 | 1702.98 |
| ALT_102420 | 2 | 01.07.2016 | 30.09.2016 | 1779.63 |
| ALT_102420 | 3 | 01.11.2016 | 30.11.2016 | 1020.60 |

And the outcome table should look like this:

| MesspNr | RechnNr | AbDat | BisDat | NettBetr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ALT_102420 | 1 | 01.04.2016 | 30.04.2016 | 567.66 |
| ALT_102420 | 1 | 01.05.2016 | 31.05.2016 | 567.66 |
| ALT_102420 | 1 | 01.06.2016 | 30.06.2016 | 567.66 |
| ALT_102420 | 2 | 01.07.2016 | 30.07.2016 | 593.21 |
| ALT_102420 | 2 | 01.08.2016 | 31.08.2016 | 593.21 |
| ALT_102420 | 2 | 01.09.2016 | 30.09.2016 | 593.21 |
| ALT_102420 | 3 | 01.11.2016 | 30.11.2016 | 1020.60 |

I have tried it using the solution on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65353239/sql-query-to-split-the-rows-according-to-date-range-one-day-using-sql-query-in-m) link but I can't get it to work. Even in it's "purest" copy pasted form it just sets AbDat and BisDat to the same Date and doesn't create new rows. I would greatly appriciate any form of help on splitting the price and creating new rows.

Comment: Has your data a Primary Key?

Comment: Hi Thomas, I didn't create the original table but no it doesn't have a PK or a combined PK for some weird reason

Comment: @FunThomas i just updated the other table so that it includes an incremental PK (1, 2, 3,...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a small query and save it as `Ten`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT Abs([id] Mod 10) AS N FROM MSysObjects;
```

Then use this in a *Cartesian* (multiplying) query to generate the months:

```sql
SELECT 
    Betrag.MessNr, 
    Betrag.RechnNr, 
    DateAdd("m", [N], [AbDat]) AS AbDatum, 
    DateAdd("d", -1, DateAdd("m", [N] + 1, [AbDat])) AS BisDatum, 
    [NettBetr] / (1 + DateDiff("m", [AbDat], [BisDat])) AS NettBetrag
FROM 
    Betrag, 
    Ten
WHERE
    Ten.N <= DateDiff("m", [AbDat], [BisDat])
ORDER BY 
    Betrag.MessNr, 
    Betrag.RechnNr, 
    DateAdd("m", [N], [AbDat]);
```

Output:

| MessNr | RechnNr | AbDatum | BisDatum | NettBetrag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ALT_102420 | 1 | 01-04-2016 | 30-04-2016 | 567,66 |
| ALT_102420 | 1 | 01-05-2016 | 31-05-2016 | 567,66 |
| ALT_102420 | 1 | 01-06-2016 | 30-06-2016 | 567,66 |
| ALT_102420 | 2 | 01-07-2016 | 31-07-2016 | 593,21 |
| ALT_102420 | 2 | 01-08-2016 | 31-08-2016 | 593,21 |
| ALT_102420 | 2 | 01-09-2016 | 30-09-2016 | 593,21 |
| ALT_102420 | 3 | 01-11-2016 | 30-11-2016 | 1020,60 |

Comment: Interesting solution. For OP and future readers, can you explain the *small query*? Why `MSysObjects`?

Comment: +1 Thank you very much @Gustav. It definitely is the correct way to the solution. The only thing i need to figure out is why it is not showing the first month. right now it begins at 01.05.2016 instead of 01.04.2016

Comment: @Parfait: That table always exists, thus - if you don't want a separate query - it can be included in the main query as a subquery.

Comment: I used your sample data directly. If the first date is "missing", the sample probably isn't representative.

Comment: @Gustav Yeah, i was using my sample data as well but for some reason it didn't show the first month. After a bit of experimenting I figured it out. I changed the <= expression in where to a <.

Ty again for you help :)