# MS Access: How to create a report that how many dates are missing in the database

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-reports

I have a dataset in MS Access and I enter data through a form. I am entering the data date wise but I want to create a report which shows that how many dates are missing in the database from a specific date. Help me to create it.

Comment: I think you may a temp table and vba macro to create all dates between your specific dates. Then use `NOT EXIST` method to finds which dates are missing. I am not sure either you can do it directly without temp table.

Comment: It is possible for query to generate a dataset of all dates between a given range. However, this type of query can perform slowly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34142019/create-a-list-of-dates-in-access-query?msclkid=3b9b35f6c46311ecb2ec38de8e8ba3c2

Answer (score 0):

You could create three tables (each table has one field):

1. [Months] will have 12 records, one for each MonthNumber.
2. [Days] will have 31 records, one for each DayNumber.
3. [Years] will have a record for each possible YearNumber.

Then create a query (call it AllDates) to generate all possible dates from those three tables:

```
SELECT DateSerial([YearNumber],[MonthNumber],[DayNumber]) AS RangeDate
FROM [Days], [Months], [Years]
WHERE (((IsDate([MonthNumber] & "/" & [DayNumber] & "/" & [YearNumber]))=True));
```

Then, your report query could be:

```
PARAMETERS StartDate DateTime, EndDate DateTime;
SELECT AllDates.*
FROM AllDates LEFT JOIN FormDates ON AllDates.RangeDate = FormDates.DateEntered
WHERE (((FormDates.DateEntered) Is Null) AND ((AllDates.RangeDate)>=[StartDate] And (AllDates.RangeDate)<=[EndDate]));
```

FYI: The [FormDates] table is the table you already have (i.e. entered from your form)