# Create Query adding dates based on a date span from a form

Tags: ms-access

Idea is to create a temporary table (or query) that will have a start_date and end_date based on a form.
Start_Date=frmForm1.StartDate
End_Date=frmForm1.EndDate

Start_Date=1/16/2020
End_Date=5/18/2024

I am looking to create a return record set that will insert into the temp table (or query record set) the following:

1/16/2020
2/1/2020
3/1/2020
4/1/2020
5/1/2020
Etc until the last record
Last record should be 5/18/2024

Any suggestions?

Append, Update, no ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a List of Dates in Access Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34142019/create-a-list-of-dates-in-access-query)

Comment: Query method is possible but can perform slowly with large dataset. Alternative is looping structure in VBA procedure that writes records to table. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41817502/insert-multiple-records-with-a-date-range-in-ms-access

Comment: @June7: "slow" is perhaps not the word: [https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Date#datasets---sets-of-dates](VBA.Date sets-of-dates). For example: _All months of one century   .03s_.